# Undefined return value using useState and firebase for objects in React Native

Tags: android, reactjs, firebase, react-native, use-state

I'm writing an app using React Native and I came across an issue when trying to update an Object with the `useState` method. Here's my code:

```
const Screen = ({route}) => {

    var roomKey = route.params;

    const [room, setRoom] = useState({});
    db.ref('rooms').on('value', (data) => {
        setRoom(() => (data.val())[roomKey]);
    });

    console.log(room);

// rest of the code ...
```

My code works as follows: first it takes a key outputted by another screen with react navigation, and then calls the firebase database with the ref method (db is defined as `Firebase.initializeApp(config).database()`, where `config` is the object with all the firebase datas needed). If I log out the `data.val())[roomKey]` it correctly outputs the object I'm downloading from database, however the `room` object is not updated by the `useState` method (it outputs `undefined`, making the following part of the code crash). What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

In your code, `setRoom` is a function to change the value of `room` state. So, you have to pass the value into the `setRoom`.

Please check the following code.

```
const Screen = ({route}) => {

    var roomKey = route.params;

    const [room, setRoom] = useState({});
    db.ref('rooms').on('value', (data) => {
        setRoom(data.val()[roomKey]);
    });

    console.log(room);

// rest of the code ...
```